# Query Taxonomy By Page Title

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

What I want to do is display posts that share a taxonomy on a page with that taxonomies name.

For example, a page named "PHP" would display all the of posts with the custom taxonomy "language" set to "PHP".

What I have so far..

```
$secondary_loop = new WP_Query(array( 'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'language',
                'terms'    => get_the_title()
            ) ), 
            'posts_per_page' => 5 ));

        while ( $secondary_loop->have_posts() ) : $secondary_loop->the_post();
            the_title();
            the_date('m/d/y');
            the_excerpt();
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

As of right now, this does not display any of the posts, but does give me..

```
object(WP_Query)#248 (46) { ["query"]=> array(2) { ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "language" ["terms"]=> string(22) "PHP" } } ...
```

When I `var_dump($secondary_loop)`. So I know it retrieves the title, which matches the taxonmy value, but it fails to display it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define the field in the array then it defaults to ID. Your options are term_id, name and slug: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'language',
        'field'    => 'name',
        'terms'    => get_the_title()
    )
)
```

Comment: I've added the `'field'` key, but it still doesn't display any posts on my page.